# Arranging One Mesh Over Plane Mesh

Tags: mesh, blender-internal-render-engine, layers

I created a plane mesh (ground) and then another mesh (tree).

On `right view`, it seems like this:

[image]

However on `top view`, the tree doesn't seem there. I also tried boosting the z-value but it doesn't come on top of ground any how. (But for right view, it goes high if I change the z).

[image]

Also when I start tilting a little in the `right view`, It becomes like these: [image] [image]

And in render, it creates an unexpected shade on the tree which I believe the above problem is causing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unexpected shading could either be flipped normals, or a lack of lighting. You could try turning on "Ambient Occlusion" in the display settings tab to help you be able to see the tree in top-down mode. It's not showing because it's the same color as the groun.

Comment: Ambient Occlusion solved my issue. Cheers!